# Select not null column from a Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Multi-statement TVF, which is returning 50 columns but almost 20 columns would definitely be NULL always. (those 20 columns are dynamic). How to identify the nullable columns dynamically and select not nullable columns.

Function:

```
Create function inlineFn 
Returns Table 
As 
    Return Select Col1...Col50 
    From Tbl 
GO

Select * from inlineFn Where (Cols) IS NOT NULL
```

Please note: We are not sure about which are those Cols.

Comment: You can't.  The table valued function has to return a result set with known columns -- after all, how could a query refer to a specific column, if the function doesn't know what it is returning.  Perhaps you want a stored procedure instead.  In a stored procedure, you can use dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want.

Comment: You can't have a dynamic number of columns on a table valued function

Comment: The function is having specific set of columns. Where as over / above the function, I am writing a select clause.

Comment: "specific set of columns", "those 20 columns are dynamic"...which one is it?

Comment: I understand it like he doesn't know which columns will return nulls, it is configurable or something like that.

Comment: Lets consider a function like below.  function(col1,...col50).. from this 50 columns, I am not sure which column will return NULL.
Select * from func where cols is NOT NULL

Comment: Imagine an Excel sheet, where you remove NULL cells and left shift all cells to the right of the removed cell. Would be very hard to understand what's what when done...

Comment: What's actually wrong with returning the null columns?

Comment: I might have confused you all with the actual question.

**Function**:
Create function inlineFn
Returns Table
As
Return

Select Col1...Col50
From Tbl
Go

Select * from inlineFn
Where **(Cols)** IS NOT NULL

Please note: We are not sure about which are those Cols.

Comment: @Andrew: Those NULL columns are not required for the intented receiver

Comment: Do you know that multi statement table valued functions are about the worst construct for performance in sql server? Do you really need multiple statements or can the function be reworked so it isn't multi statement?

Comment: @SeanLange: We deliberately need Multi-statement TVF due to some unavoidable complex design.

Comment: Why do you not know which columns can return NULL?   Don't you have access to the TVF code?

Comment: Then I would consider using a stored procedure instead. The performance of multi statement table functions is truly awful.